# MVC detect when model is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, so I'm trying to figure out some best practices.

Suppose I have a controller `HomeController` method `Index(MyViewModel model)`:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    //if loading the page for the first time, do nothing
    //if the page has been posted data from somewhere, then I want to use
    //  some of the arguments in model to load other data, like say search results
}
```

When I navigate to the `/Index` page, I (myself) expect the `model` object to come through as null, but it doesn't. MVC (somehow) creates a `MyViewModel` for me.

My question is, what's the best way or most consistent to determine if `model` was created automatically, or via a post?

Ideas:

- Create a property on `MyViewModel` that gets set when the view is posting back
- Check for if the `Request.HttpMethod == "GET"` or `"POST"`
- Something else?

Comment: Automatic binding may create a MyViewModel but are the values populated? The model properties are likely null.

Comment: If you are asking about whether, the form was posted? attach [HttpPost] attribute to your method, the one expecting a model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use different actions for your GET and POST requests. Don't try and make a single method do too much.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // handle the GET request
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // it's a post and the data is valid
    }
}
```

The correct method will then be called depending on whether it's a GET or POST

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that if I had two methods, I could return `View()` on the Post one and have it still direct to `Index`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create two actions, one which accepts a model instance and one which doesn't.

Even though you're "going to the same page" you are in fact performing two distinctly different actions.  The first action loads an initial page, the second action posts some value to be acted upon.  Two actions means two methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // perform any logic, but you probably just want to return the view
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // respond to the model in some way
    return View(model);
    // or return something else?  a redirect?  it's up to you
}
```

Note that this kind of breaks your restful URLs.  Consider semantically what you're doing in these actions:

- Viewing an index
- Posting to an index

The first one makes sense, but the second one probably doesn't.  Normally when you `POST` something you're *doing* something related to a model or action of some sort.  "Index" doesn't really describe an action.  Are you "Create"-ing something?  Are you "Edit"-ing something?  Those sound like more meaningful action names for the `POST` action.